# How do i make an .append using a for loop in a <select> dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is what i have so far
i am getting an error relating parentheses

```
var teachers = ['mrs ohara','mr decrenza','mrs poli'];
$('#addteacher').on('click',function(){

      $('#home').hide();
      console.log();
      $('#home').append('<select id = "teacherdropdown"><option>heloo</option></select>');
      for (var i = 0;i++;i<teachers.length){
        $('#teacherdropdown').append("<option value = "+teachers[i]+">"+teachers[i]+"</option>");
      }
})
```

Comment: note quoting the attribute value for `<option value=`. The quotes you do have are only string termination quotes

Comment: yes what about it?

Comment: missing the quotes to wrap the actual value

Comment: You don't have to quote attributes in html, although it is odd to have spaces around the '=' sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your for condition the wrong way around:

```
for (var i = 0;i++;i<teachers.length)
```

Should be

```
for (var i = 0;i<teachers.length;i++)
```

Working fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/qoxxjudp/